# Typo3 signal on change of fe_users table

Tags: typo3, signals, typo3-extensions, slots

I have good experiences in writing extensions but I am new at signals and slots. I want to do something with users when table fe_users was changed. I can't find any example to start with. All examples are written in general. I can't use it yet because of my lack of experience in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it through the Middleware approach. It's future safe.

Sources that helped a lot:
 - https://usetypo3.com/psr15-middleware-in-typo3.html
 - https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html